# How do I burn an MKV with picture-based subtitles into a DVD?

Tags: dvd, subtitles, matroska, dvd-burning

I'm trying to figure out how to burn a series of MKV files with picture-based subtitles (not srt) to a video DVD but I can't figure out how to achieve this. I tried DVDStyler and it did import the video but it did not include the embedded subtitles.

By the way, do video DVDs even support picture-based subtitles to begin with? I'm not very familiar with burning DVDs and am just curious about the whole process.

Comment: DVD subtitles are bitmap. It's just they are not a "simple" stream like the MPEG-2 video or the audio which reside purely in the VOBs (but have metadata like display time and color palette in an IFO, IIRC). I am not sure if there's any software that well support creating a VIDEO_TS tree with subtitle created from other kind of bitmap subtitles / image overlays / vobsub idx/sub pairs. Not even many software does the opposite (extraction) really well, AFAIK.

Comment: Hi @TomYan, I looked into it more and it seems what I have are called SSA subtitles. Is there no DVD authoring tools that can deal with it? I don't mind even if it's paid software.

Comment: There could be, but I don't know any. AFAIK most of them doesn't care much in subtitle support.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1** - Extract the picture-based subtitles from your MKV files. You can do this with [MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/).

**Step 2** - You'll need to convert the extracted subtitles to VobSub (IDX/SUB) format, which is compatible with DVDs. You can use [Subtitle Edit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases) to do this.

**Step 3** -  Now, you can use [DVDStyler](https://www.dvdstyler.org/en/) to create your DVD. Import the video and the converted VobSub subtitles into your DVDStyler project.

**Step 4** - Once your DVD project is ready, save it and use the authoring software to create the DVD structure (as a VIDEO_TS folder).

**Step 5** - Now you can use a DVD burning software like [ImgBurn](https://www.imgburn.com/) to burn the project to a blank DVD.